# Inverse matrix from LU С++

Tags: c

I have 2 functions decomp and solve, after executing solve I need to pull out the inverse matrix A from there.

```
void Decomp(unsigned int n, Float *A, Float *cond, int *ipvt)
{
    unsigned int i, j, k;
    int kp1, m;
    Float ek, t, anorm, ynorm, znorm, *work;
    if(!n) return;//размерность матрицы не может быть нулевой
    ipvt[n-1]=1;
    if(n == 1)//Случай матрицы 1x1
    {
        *cond = 1.0;
        if(*A == 0.0) *cond = MAXIMUM;//Точная вырожденность
        return;
    }

    //Вычислить 1-норму матрицы A
    anorm = 0.0;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        t=0.0;
        for(i=j;i<n*n;i+=n) t += ABS(A[i]);
        if (t > anorm) anorm = t;
    }

    //Гауссова исключение с частичным выбором ведущего элемента
    for(k=0;k<(n-1);k++)
    {
        kp1 = k + 1;
        //Найти ведущий элемент
        m = k*n+k;
        for(i=(kp1*n + k);i<n*n;i+=n) if(ABS(A[i]) > ABS(A[m])) m = i;
        m /= n;
        ipvt[k] = m;
        if(m != k) ipvt[n-1] = -ipvt[n-1];

        t = A[m*n+k];
        A[m*n+k] = A[k*(n+1)];
        A[k*(n+1)] = t;

        //Пропустить этот шаг, если ведущий элемент равен нулю
        if(t != 0.0)
        {
            //Вычислить множители
            for(i=(kp1*n + k);i<n*n;i+=n) A[i] = -A[i]/t;
            //Переставлять и исключать по столбцам
            for(j=kp1;j<n;j++)
            {
                int temp = k-j;

                t = A[m*n+j];
                A[m*n+j] = A[k*n+j];
                A[k*n+j] = t;

                if(t != 0.0) for(i=(kp1*n+j);i<n*n;i+=n) A[i] += A[i+temp]*t;
            }
        }
    }

    work = new Float[n];
    //Решить систему (транспонированная A)*Y = I
    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        t=0.0;
        if(k != 0) for(i=k,j=0;j<(k-1);i+=n, j++) t += A[i]*work[j];
        if(t < 0.0) ek = -1.0;
        else ek = 1.0;
        Float temp = A[k*(n+1)];
        if(temp == 0.0)
        {
            *cond = MAXIMUM;
            delete [] work;
            return;
        }
        work[k] = -(ek+t)/temp;
    }

    k = n-2;
    do
    {
        t = work[k];
        kp1 = k+1;
        for(i=kp1*n+k,j=kp1; j<n; i+=n,j++) t += A[i]*work[j];
        work[k] = t;
        m = ipvt[k];
        if(m != k)
        {
            t = work[m];
            work[m] = work[k];
            work[k] = t;
        }
    }while(k--);

    ynorm = 0.0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) ynorm += ABS(work[i]);
    //Решить систему A*Z = Y
    Solve(n, A, work, ipvt);
    znorm=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) znorm += ABS(work[i]);
    //Оценить обусловленность
    *cond = anorm*znorm/ynorm;
    if (*cond < 1.0) *cond = 1.0;
    delete [] work;
}


void Solve(unsigned int n, Float *A, Float *b, int *ipvt)
{
    unsigned int k, i;
    int m;
    Float t;
    if(!n) return;
    //Прямой ход
    if(n == 1)
    {
        b[0] /= *A;
        return;
    }

    for(k=0;k<(n-1);k++)
    {
        m = ipvt[k];

        t = b[m];
        b[m] = b[k];
        b[k] = t;

        for(i=k+1;i<n;i++) b[i] += A[i*n+k]*t;
    }
    //Обратная подстановка
    for(k=n-1;k>0;k--)
    {
        b[k] /= A[k*(n+1)];
        t = -b[k];
        for(i=0;i<k;i++) b[i] += A[i*n+k]*t;
    }
    b[0] /= *A;
}
```

Of course, I could just calculate the inverse matrix, but that's the task.

I have no idea how to do this.
All I have found was this piece of code, but it doesn’t interfere with my functions at all

```
        double cond;
        int pivot[8];
        int flag;
        decomp(8, 8, matrix, &cond, pivot, &flag);
        double invertedMatrix[64];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            double b[8]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
            b[i] = 1;
            solve(8, 8, matrix, b, pivot);
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
                invertedMatrix[i + j * n] = b[j];
        }
```

Comment: I don't know how efficient this would be but there's a suggestion here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition So you already have A= LU, and you want A^-1, then you solve L[UX] = I, then UX = [UX] giving X = A^-1.